# Nvidia optimus NvOptimusEnablement

Tags: c++, directx, nvidia

I have dual GPU's, Intel HD and Nvidia GPU. I want to force my application to use Nvidia GPU. 
So I created header file

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

and then included into my cpp file where I'm creating device with Nvidia adapter

```
D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(dxgiAdapter, D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        0, 0, D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc,
           &pSwapChain, &pDevice);
```

where `dxgiAdapter` is `dxgiFactory -> EnumAdapters(1, &dxgiAdapter_);`

```
1
```

is Nvidia GPU index, 0 - intel HD GPU index.

but my program still using intel's GPU.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `nullptr` instead of `dxgiAdapter`, `NvOptimusEnablement` should handle it itself. For example on my machine the nvidia GPU is on the first place and then Intel HD Graphics, so you might be selecting Intel after all. And make sure that somewhere in the nvidia control panel you have set the preferred graphics processor to be auto-selected.

Comment: I passed nullptr but same no result. Also nullptr is causing nvwgf2um.dll exception.

Comment: Why are you even using D3D10? Why not 11?

Comment: Same result with D3D11 and also with D3D12. I have this nvwgf2um.dll exception anyway. 

1. KERNELBASE.dll(RaiseException)
2. nvwgf2um.dll
3. KERNEL32.DLL(BaseThreadInitThunk)
4. ntdll.dll(RtlValidSecurityDescriptor)

Comment: @Alatriste Maybe post the entire source code, maybe something different is causing this issue

Comment: @Alatriste It's not a whole code though, but ok, nevermind. Just in case, are your drivers working properly? Maybe update them or reinstall? Some quick googling showed me that it might be drivers. Code looks good to me

Comment: I mean there is whole DirectX code, nothing else. Yes I reinstalled drivers, installed old versions, but nothing helped.

Comment: @Alatriste At which point does the breakpoint exactly trigger? During the device creation, or swap chain or what?

Comment: This problem is caused when I'm calling IDXGISwapChain::Present(0,0)

Comment: @Alatriste So either something with drivers or a problem with your swap chain

Comment: what problem can be with my swap chain? You saw the code, some wrong initialization parameter?

Comment: @Alatriste Maybe try to set `BufferCount` to 1 instead of 2 and `Flags` to 0

Comment: I set but no result.. it's so simple an minimal code.. What can be wrong here.